# Programmatically showing a View from an Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

I have a plug-in to an Eclipse RCP application that has a view.  After an event occurs in the RCP application, the plug-in is instantiated, its methods are called to populate the plug-in's model, but I cannot find how to make the view appear without going to the "Show View..." menu.

I would think that there would be something in the workbench singleton that could handle this, but I have not found out how anywhere.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("viewId");
```

Comment: It is important to note that the arg0 can be a view part's VIEW_ID field.

Comment: Where do I put that? I put it in all my classes, but still doesn't work. (I accidentally closed the view within the RCP application)

Answer (score 20):

If called from handler of a command

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView(viewId);
```

would be better, as I know.

Answer (score 5):

I found the need to bring the view to the front after it had been opened and pushed to the background.  The activate method does the trick.

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage()
    .activate(workbenchPartToActivate);
```

NOTE: The workbenchPartToActivate is an instance of `IWorkbenchPart`.

Answer (score 0):

In e4, the EPartService is responsible for opening Parts. This can also be used to open e3 ViewParts. Instantiate the following class through your IEclipseContext, call the openPart-Method, and you should see the Eclipse internal browser view.

```
public class Opener {
    @Inject
    EPartService partService;

    public void openPart() {
        MPart part = partService.createPart("org.eclipse.ui.browser.view");
        part.setLabel("Browser");

        partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Services/article.html#selectedservices_partservice5) you can find an example of how this works together with your Application.e4xmi.