# In Eclipse plugin development how do I programmatically activate a view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I have a tree view that is acting as a selection provider. In response to different types of selected items I would like to show a view. (Instantiate it is needed).

Can I do this by VIEW_ID and the workbench getViewRegistry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically showing a View from an Eclipse Plug-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171824/programmatically-showing-a-view-from-an-eclipse-plug-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic technique is described best by the article
"[Make your Eclipse applications richer with view linking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/?ca=dgr-lnxw09EclipseGUIviews)",
based on a "selection provider-selection listener" pattern, which is a handy way to create views that respond to changes in other views, updated now with the [**Selection Service**](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2008/01/14/the-selection-service/).

Something like:

```
IViewRegistry viewRegistry = this.getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench().getViewRegistry();
IViewDescriptor desc = viewRegistry.find(VIEW_ID);
window.getActivePage().showView(VIEW_ID);
```

should be able to open/create the view