# Open a View in Eclipse Plug-in programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to eclipse plug-in development, and have a little question here.

I want to open a new view by clicking on an object in an editor. Specifically, the object is a link to an image file, that should be opened in an image viewer. For now, I'm using

```
ImageViewer viewer = (ImageViewer) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewer_ID);
viewer.setSelection(pathToFile);
```

is this how you would normally do it (both opening the view, and getting the image to it), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171824/programmatically-showing-a-view-from-an-eclipse-plug-in), your code is the way to go, but there's a slightly more stable way to do it within a Handler.

Once you opened the view, you can use any of its API.