# How to execute a view from another view of a Eclipse plug-in programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I have a view in a eclipse plug-in. I need to open a view on a action of hyperlink in the current view.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it. Here are the steps to do it:

- Find the context you are in.
- `page = self.getSite().getPage();` gets the page from where to open the view.
- `page.showView(<ID of page>);`

See the questions:

- [Open a view programatically](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t115006.html)
- [How to open a view programatically?](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/296197/)
- Stackoverflow: [Programmatically showing a View from an Eclipse Plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171824/programmatically-showing-a-view-from-an-eclipse-plug-in)