# Make a table appear automatically in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, interface, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

How make a table appear automatically in an Eclipse plugin?

I am currently developing an eclipse plugin and I created this option in the plugin that provides me a table on the "view". However, every time when I want to see the table, I have to do this process:

Window -> Show View -> Other -> My Table

Doing this process is not user friendly. Is there a way to make this table appear automatically when I click my option button and refreshes it every time when I click it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171824/programmatically-showing-a-view-from-an-eclipse-plug-in to see how to open a view programmatically.